# Tibble 3.0 broke casen package. Error: No common type for `..1` <svyby<>> and `..2` <data.frame<>>

Tags: r, dplyr, survey, tibble, rlang

## casen package

`casen::` is a package to obtain correct estimates for complex designs.

After the release of tibble 3.0 I got this email from CRAN:

> Dear maintainer,
>
> Please see the problems shown on
>   https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_casen.html.
>
> The new check problems are from a recent upgrade of package 'tibble'
>   to version 3.0.0, with breaking changes described at
>   https://tibble.tidyverse.org/news/index.html.
>
> We understand that you were not informed by the tibble maintainer
>   about the upcoming breakage, and many of us currently have very little
>   time to work on their packages. Can you nevertheless please try to fix
>   your package as quickly as possible? If the description of the
>   breaking changes does not suffice, please feel free to ask the tibble
>   maintainer for help.
>
> Please correct before 2020-04-22 to safely retain your package on
>   CRAN.

## MWE and required fix

Here's a MWE that illustrates what needs to be fixed in the package so it's not removed from CRAN:

### What works

Just as inside the package, but simplified.

```
# packages

# devtools::install_github("pachamaltese/casen")
# or
# install.packages("casen")

library(casen)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

# set up a complex design and variables, just as in the package

disenio <- configuracion_disenio(datos = casen_2017_los_rios,
                                 variable = "ytotcorh",
                                 agrupacion = c("comuna", "sexo"),
                                 peso = "expc")

d_groups = disenio$grupos
des = disenio$disenio
stat_fun = srvyr::survey_mean
agrupacion = disenio$agrupacion
conglomerado = disenio$conglomerado
estrato = disenio$estrato
peso = disenio$peso
variable = disenio$variable
col_prefix = "media_"

# set j = 1 for the MWE

j <- 1

# here is a fraction of the package internals

filter_values <- d_groups %>% dplyr::slice(j)
filter_syms <- purrr::map2(names(filter_values), filter_values, ~rlang::expr(!!sym(.x) == !!.y))

des2 <- des %>%
  dplyr::filter(!!!filter_syms)
```

### What doesn't work

This worked with older `tibble::` versions

```
# also taken from the package

des2 <- des2 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(!!!syms(c(agrupacion))) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    !!sym(paste0(col_prefix, variable)) := stat_fun(!!sym(variable), vartype = "ci", df = survey::degf(des2))
  )

Error: No common type for `..1` <svyby<>> and `..2` <data.frame<>>.
```

## My setup

I installed the full tidyverse from github in order to reproduce the errors reported in CRAN. Here is the `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] purrr_0.3.3       dplyr_0.8.99.9002 rlang_0.4.5.9000  casen_0.1.3       testthat_2.3.2   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4         compiler_3.6.3     pillar_1.4.3       forcats_0.5.0.9000
 [5] tools_3.6.3        pkgload_1.0.2      lifecycle_0.2.0    tibble_3.0.0      
 [9] lattice_0.20-40    pkgconfig_2.0.3    Matrix_1.2-18      DBI_1.1.0         
[13] cli_2.0.2          rstudioapi_0.11    haven_2.2.0        srvyr_0.3.8       
[17] withr_2.1.2        generics_0.0.2     desc_1.2.0         vctrs_0.2.99.9010 
[21] mitools_2.4        hms_0.5.3          rprojroot_1.3-2    grid_3.6.3        
[25] tidyselect_1.0.0   glue_1.4.0         R6_2.4.1           fansi_0.4.1       
[29] survival_3.1-11    tidyr_1.0.2.9000   magrittr_1.5       backports_1.1.6   
[33] ellipsis_0.3.0     splines_3.6.3      labelled_2.2.2     assertthat_0.2.1  
[37] utf8_1.1.4         survey_4.0         crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this problem. I have `tibble 3.0.1`.